# Has anyone had to sign a form from Mouser before an order was allowed? (Nucleo Board)

Tags: stm32, embedded, nucleo

Not sure if it's exactly the right place but here it goes.

I was ordering a STM32 Nucleo board for the first time (the NUCLEO-F756ZG), along with other parts as I'm working on my own project for one and wanted to get into using the STM line (just graduated and didn't get to learn it in school.)

To my surprise today I opened my email and was told that my order is on hold until I sign a form that has to be sent to an export department.

It's asking for my personal info such as my Federal Tax ID #, if I've ever been convicted of any crimes like export violations, or if I'm on any lists, what I intend to use the product for, etc.

What gives? I haven't been able to find anything online about this with anyone else ordering these boards. I live in the United States.

Is this a normal thing or is there some mistake? I don't want to be on some list for just trying to learn something.

Comment: Perhaps it misread 'Nucleo' as 'nuclear' and thinks you might be trying to make an atomic bomb?

Comment: Sounds like there's something ITAR restricted on that board ...

Comment: @brhans indeed it is EAR not specified ITAR but says on mouser " EAR Alert:
 This product may require additional documentation to export from the United States", this is likely a commercial exporter issue not a secret issue, but maybe

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_Administration_Regulations

Comment: Does your name or your travel history suggest a connection with one of the countries on the US's long "naughty list"?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I was born here, have what you can consider an American name, and never have been outside of the country. Heck the furthest I've been is Baltimore (I'm in NYC).
I did not see the EAR, I ended up using Mouser last minute because Digikey did not have the board and I didn't want to pay a big shipping fee twice from two companies.

Comment: @brhans A bit confused, I have no intention of exporting it and I live in the US.

Comment: The USG has a very liberal interpretation of "exporting" which does not necessarily involve you or the product leaving the country. But strange in any case, maybe just a reminder of their concerns. NXP wanted to know the end use of an LCD (no doubt China-made) that I just ordered for shipment to Canada.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Just my luck I chose the one with this restriction. I sent an email to them just to see what they would say, but maybe I'll just request to swap to another Nucleo board for my order instead.

Comment: EAR isn't triggered by you, the end user; it's triggered by the product's capabilities. I've had to fill out EAR99 declarations for shipping *prototype* product from our USA HQ to one of our domestic USA satellite offices (Colorado, one of the landlocked states), *for internal evaluation*, and export control still needs all their legal paperwork. In particular the Nucleo is a high-speed microcontroller, at some point it becomes "powerful" enough to become useful for encryption (which is considered as munitions). Some massive tariff document somewhere outlines what qualifies as EAR99 ("safe").

Comment: I would definitely call Mouser and double-check if it is a mistake. But I don't see any harm in just filling out the forms to get your order.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the topic of purchasing/shipping electronics is off-topic.

Comment: @mkeith I contacted them and explained that it's not being exported, etc, and they said "we just require the signed EUC form with that information for auditing purposes.". I really have no problem with the form but the Federal ID request seemed off to me.

Comment: Makes sense. But I have reasonable trust in Mouser, Digikey, Arrow, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This board is listed on their website with an EAR (Export Administration Regulations) due to it contain ART Accelerator. If you really live in the United States, this shouldn't trigger it. But probably they flagged you for some unknown reason that could be shipping to a hotel address, or not US issued credit card. It's impossible to know and they probably will never say why you were flagged.

Comment: I live in NYC, born and raised here, and shipped it to my home. My first thought was to check if the address was incorrect. I used my Discover card. My address is correct. What do I do? Should I contact them and say there must be some mistake?

Comment: Actually, in the address I put in the ATTN: field c/o *name here* (in care of), because sometimes the mailman doesn't see my name on the list and don't want my package to be left in the hall. Is this something that could of triggered?

Comment: Digikey asks me every order. Microchip do the same when I want samples - even when I was working for a large US military contractor!

Comment: Most likely, they want some assurance that you aren't buying it with the intention of immediately exporting it to a prohibited country.